# Previous visa copies for a Schengen visa application

Tags: schengen, overstaying

I need to apply for a Schengen visa from Switzerland. In the application, it asks for previous visa copies. I have lost my previous UK BRP card. What should I need to do? Do I need to provide visa copies for the last 5 years? If it is the last 5 years, my UK visa BRP card was issued before 5 years but my stay falls within the 5 years. What should I do?

@toy: https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4022/toy I think you had a similar experience. Appreciate your advice.

Comment: There is no place in the Schengen application for visa copies, it asks for previously issued and rejected visa dates. Can you post a scan of where it is asking you for this?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks for your reply.
4 - Photocopy of all visas (valid and expired) of last 5 years
https://www.tm.lk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Schengen-Reqirments.pdf

Comment: Where are you applying from? The site you linked is not an official source of information for Schengen visas

Comment: I got it from vsfglobal site. updated link https://www.vfsglobal.ch/switzerland/srilanka/pdf/Checklist-for-BUSINESS-TRAINING-WORKSHOP-and-SEMINAR.pdf

Comment: This seems like a bizarre thing in relation to Sri Lanka specifically???

Answer (score 2):

The Schengen visa application asks for passports, current and previous, as well as photocopies of all visas, valid and expired of the last 5 years.

A UK Biometric Residence Permit (BRP) is not a visa, but a secure identity card which contains personal details and biometric information for those who have permission (a visa) to be remain in the UK for more than 6 months.

Separately, you were issued a UK visa, which is in either a current or a previous passport, and both of which you are expected to include with your application. At this point, you should include all that is requested, even that which may not reflect positively on visa or immigration history.